# Nhibernate unit testing. Child class cannot use Base class property

Tags: unit-testing, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mstest

I am using Fluent NHibernate and trying to do unit testing. Now I have a base test class which looks as follows:

```
[TestClass]
public abstract class BaseTest<TEntity> where TEntity : IBaseModel
{
    private const string testDbFile = "test.db";
    private static ISessionFactory sessionFactory;
    protected static ISession session;

    [TestMethod]
    public void configureDB()
    {
        try
        {
            if (sessionFactory == null)
            {
                sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                                .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard
                                    .UsingFile(testDbFile))
                                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<AdminTest>())
                                .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
                                .BuildSessionFactory();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
        }
    }

    private static void BuildSchema(Configuration config)
    {
        new SchemaUpdate(config).Execute(false, true);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void sessionCreated()
    {
        session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public virtual void AddEntity_EntityWasAdded()
    {
        var entity = BuildEntity();

        InsertEntity(entity);

        session.Evict(entity);

        var reloadedEntity = session.Get<TEntity>(entity.Id);

        Assert.IsNotNull(reloadedEntity);
        AssertAreEqual(entity, reloadedEntity);
        AssertValidId(reloadedEntity);
    }
```

There are also other methods which update and delete an entity. And I have `AdminTest` class which inherits `BaseTest`. In `AdminTest` I have following method:

```
[TestClass]
public class AdminTest : BaseTest<Admin>
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void SelectWorks()
    {
        IList<Admin> admins = session.QueryOver<Admin>().List();
        Assert.AreNotEqual(0, admins.Count);
    }
}
```

Here I always have exception, because session is `null`. Maybe I am wrong in the way of thinking how visual studio performs unit tests (I am newbie in it)?
Now I think like that, visual studio works in the following way

1. runs test-methods from `BaseTest` (there it configures database and creates session)
2. runs `selectWorks` method. Here I was thinking it should use `session` from `BaseTest`

Could you explain what is wrong in my way of thinking? And I want to be able to query from child classes, what is the right way of doing it?
Thanks, any help is appreciated, .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using [TestInitialize] and [TestCleanup] in your abstract base class and doing something like the following:

```
    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Get a ISession object");
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Dispose ISession");
    }
```

Then in your child classes continue to do what you are doing:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void DoDbWork()
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Running a query via nhibernate");
    }
```

You really just want to ensure you have a clean session for each test. The attributes for TestInitialize and TestCleanup will run before and after each unit test.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is the documentation for those attributes.

To ensure your ISession is in the right state,follow something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353692/what-is-the-best-nhibernate-session-management-approach-for-using-in-a-multithre).