# WCF and NHibernate transaction scope

Tags: wcf, nhibernate

I have client calls coming in to WCF Service and then through Fluent NHibernate querying the db.

At the moment WCF is left as it's default (i.e., per call).

And in my code I do something like this:

```
using (_repository.DbContext.BeginTransaction()) {
    try {
        _repository.SavePerson(object);
        _repository1.SaveAddress(object1);
    } catch {
        _repository.DbContext.RollbackTransaction();
        throw;
    }
}
```

since `DbContext` is the same for both `_repository` and `_repository1`. Do I need to do a RollBack on `_repository1`?

Also now since the Save methods in the repositories, 
the Session object is used to save the objects.

What I need to know is,
is this Session the same for both calls, or are they 2 different ones? I am assuming they to be the same since
I am grouping them in transaction scope as one unit of work.

Also How does this coordinate with WCF calls, do I need to handle transactions from WCF side as well?

Comment: This is my answer which should help http://stackoverflow.com/a/15451070/168048

Answer (score 0):

Your question can not be answered by someone who does not have access to your code. NHibernate session are not created by WCF, you do have some custom code for creating a session. If you want do stuff to r1 and r2 at the same time and rollback only r1, you need to have to sessions with a transaction on each session. Now you can rollback r1 without touching r2.

The solution is to open a second session from your session factory.